# Listing only shared document (Anyone in my Org can find and access) count through API

Tags: google-drive-api

We are looking to fetch list and count of shared document(Anyone in my Org can find and access)through API  . Already enabled API from Google console . but not sure how to use the API query for that specific visibility document.

Comment: I assume you want a list of the files that have been shared with everyone in your organization. What type of [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource) did you use to grant access to these users?

Comment: Yes that's correct and also i am looking for how to list the file counts through API ?

Comment: Are we talking about all users in the domain or just from a specific OU? Also, by "list the file counts" you mean getting the number of files?